# OpenGL FrameBuffer off-screen, on-screen rendering problem with PyQT5

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, framebuffer, pyopengl

I'm trying to render to a fbo to use glReadPixels. I can render to fbo and read pixel value, but I cannot get it rendering on screen, I get an error like this:

> err = 1286,
> description = b'invalid framebuffer operation',

Here is my steps:

```
    class MyGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
        ...
        ...
        def paintGl():
           ### offscreen rendering ###

           glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fbo);
           glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
           glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
           # ... bind texture ...
           # ... shader program...
           # ... VAO
           # ... EBO
           # ... uniforms
           # ... draw

           glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) #<--- The problem is here. i don't know why
    
           ### read pixel ###
           glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fbo)
           glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
           print(glReadPixels(0, 0, _width, _height, _format, _type)) #<-- I got correct value here.

           ### on screen render ###
           glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) #<---I got an error here
           glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    
           # ... bind texture (color attachment texture)
           # ... shader program...
           # ... VAO
           # ... EBO
           glDrawElements(mode, count, _type, indices)  #<--- If i don't use glClear, I get an error here.
```

The problem is the line `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)`
If i remove that line, I don't get an error but I get black screen.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong or maybe bugs from my graphic card or bugs in QOpenGLWidget.
Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0) #<--- The problem is here. i don't know why
> ```

From the [documentation for `QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) (emphasis mine):

> All rendering happens into an OpenGL framebuffer object. [`makeCurrent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent)
> ensure that it is bound in the context. Keep this in mind when
> creating and binding additional framebuffer objects in the rendering
> code in [`paintGL()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL). **Never re-bind the framebuffer with ID 0. Instead,
> call [`defaultFramebufferObject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#defaultFramebufferObject) to get the ID that should be bound.**